# Chrome allowing cookies despite telling it not to

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, browser-cache

I have locked down Chrome to be very strict on the cookies and data it stores both temporarily and long term. I have ticked the following boxes in cookie settings:

[image: Cookie Settings]

and I currently have an exception list which looks like this [that's the complete list]:

[image: Cookie Exception List]

However, if I look at the currently saved cookies:

[image: Current cookies]

Notice there is **youtube.com**, **microsoft.com**, **msn.com**. I know that subdomains are permitted, but I would have expected cross domains to be blocked but yet somehow these are still being set. If I go to `www.youtube.com` and click the cookie icon in the omnnibox I can see that I definitely haven't allowed **youtube.com** cookies:

[image: Youtube cookies blocked]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I can't help but what a wonderfully clear question! +1

Comment: You have allowed Google which shares Cookies among all its sites (because it has a single login service).  I assume you cleared out your cookies before you blocked all third-party cookies?  A YouTube cookie created by Google isn't considerd a third-party

Comment: Yep I did a complete clear out of current site data (initially didn't want to because of the site data I wanted to keep but decided to take the plunge) so it's a fresh start. The way I understand it, I have allowed `Google.com` and it's subdomains, **NOT** Google the company. Regardless of the single sign on, I have not allowed `Youtube.com` to save a cookie, and yet it has. Same applies to Microsoft.com and Msn.com (in case Chrome, being made by Google, gave special privelages).

Answer (score 0):

Did you cleared your cookies after blocking them? I think blocking cookies will not delete existing items. It'll only prevent setting **new** cookies.

Comment: Yep I deleted all my existing cookies, I think you're correct it won't delete existing cookies so I made sure to rule that out of the equation.